# Error Connection Reset error in mern stack project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios, mern

I follow the [JavaScript Mastery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA&list=PL6QREj8te1P7VSwhrMf3D3Xt4V6_SRkhu) video for the CRUD app. I have a problem connecting the frontend with the backend. When I try to submit the form, I `console log` it. It shows the

> POST http://localhost:5000/posts net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I checked the server and database connections, and there is nothing wrong.

*Error Screenshot*

[image]

**index.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/posts';
export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url)
export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
```

**server/index.js**

```js
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/posts', postRoutes)

const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://mominriyadh:@######@cluster0.jqiet.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from one of your extensions not from your code. Whatruns to be specific. [self.processResponse is not a function #33355](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/33355)

Answer (score 0):

Include this code in index.js in server:

```
app.use(express.json());
```